# Is it possible to have one server acting as secondary for two primaries on AG?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, high-availability

Can I have a server acting as secondary replica for two primary servers on an availability group?

[image: Exemplo]

If possible, are there some concerns about performance in an async environment? Are listeners going to work that way?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean for the same database(s), if so how are there two primaries? If you mean for two different AGs, yes, one instance can be a secondary for two different AGs on two different primaries.

Comment: The primary instances are different, with several databases each.The main goal here is to save money with windows and sql server licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, the answer is Yes.  1 SQL instance can act as a secondary for multiple Availability Groups.  Listeners will point to the appropriate AG.  You may have some security concerns to address if the user base of the different AGs is a different set of users...make sure they can't access each other's databases in the case that they are read only, or acting as primary on the DR(Secondary) server.  Also, all instances will need to be a part of the same WSFC.